# Issues Uploading Sticker Pack Extension to iMessage

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode8, imessage

I created a sticker pack extension (not the full sticker app) for iMessage using Xcode 8. I have the icons too and the project gives no errors or warnings. I registered the bundle ID, archived and uploaded the archive, and created a new app. However, I don't see anything about stickers!! iTunesConnect seems to be treating it like a normal app.

In the Apple tutorial, it says there's a category called "Stickers" that I can give it but I don't see that either:

> Category. You can list your sticker pack in the Stickers category or another category that best describes your app. You can also list it in a second relevant category.

I see on [appCoda](https://www.appcoda.com/message-sticker-app/) that on June 16  (when the article below was written):

> You cannot upload your sticker pack to the Messages App Store yet.

Is it still not available two months later, like 10 days before the expected Sep 7 launch? Or is there something in the Build Info I need to change? Or the pList? Please let me know if I'm building / archiving / uploading this incorrectly and how to remedy it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple will tell you when you will be able to upload Stickers to the AppStore. This is normally right after the Keynote Event. Take into consideration that in order to upload an App to the App Store you have to use a NON Beta Distribution of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it. Just a note about the beta thing, I did upload a TestFlight build using the Xcode 8 beta today. It's not officially supposed to work, but it did.

Comment: How were you able to do this? Was it a developer build?